# How to change databinding of TextBlock by Click into ItemsControl MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I click 1 ItemsControl then It change value text but It doesn't work

**this is my code xaml in View:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FCsource}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Margin="10" Width="440" Height="220" >
                                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.MouseLeftButtonDown }" >
                                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Words}"></TextBlock>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**this is my code xaml in ViewModel:**

public ObservableCollection _FCsource;

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.MenuItem> FCsource { get { return AddFlashCard(); } set { FCsource = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

private String _Words;
public string Words { get => _Words; set { _Words = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

public RelayCommand MouseLeftButtonDown { get; set; }

public WordsViewModel()
{
    MouseLeftButtonDown = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("Message", "Hi"));
}

private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> AddFlashCard()
{
    ObservableCollection<MenuItem> listmn = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    listmn.Add(new MenuItem("qwda"));
    listmn.Add(new MenuItem("qwda"));
    return listmn;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @NamDang just post the code in question some one will edit it

Comment: I added It into question

Comment: So how is the source of the itemscountrol set? you cut out that part.

Comment: yeah , I cut It

Comment: @KevinCook I additional it

Comment: @AvinashReddy  I additional it

Comment: @RubenMartirosyan I additional it

Comment: You are recreating the FCsource on each get, how can you ever update it? Also, you are binding words, but it doesn't belong to FCsource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about writing a simple button in your DataTemplate, and then inside it put your TextBlock :

```
<Button Command="YourRelayCommand">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Words}" />
</Button>
```

Comment: But I want click ItemsControl and then It change value. Thanks for your comment